# XPath: address a value by a selector that is not parent

Tags: xml, xpath

How can I address an elementy by XPath thats selector is not above it (but at the same level)?

E.g. I want to have the value of the item with name B. Not sure hot to do it because name and value are not in a parent relationship.

```
<root>
    <item>
        <name>A</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>B</name>
        <value>2</value>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>C</name>
        <value>3</value>
    </item>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done simply as following:

```
//item[./name='B']/value
```

This literally means: find `item` element containing a direct child with `name` = "B" -> find this `item` element direct child `value`.
In case `name` and / or `value` are not the direct children of `item` the above expression will be

```
//item[.//name='B']//value
```

Another approach, in case inside each `item` there is only single `name` and single `value` can be:

```
//item[name='B']/following-sibling::value
```

Answer (score 1):

To extract the value of the item with name B there are multiple approaches as follows:

- Using *following*:

  ```
  //item/name[text()='B']//following::value[1]
  ```
- Using *following-sibling*:

  ```
  //item/name[text()='B']//following-sibling::value[1]
  ```
- Using *ancestor*:

  ```
  //name[text()='B']//ancestor::item[1]//value
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
//name[text()='B']/following-sibling::value
```

Gets the **sibling** with tag **value** of an element **name** with text **B**